# Javascript global variable is not updating

Tags: javascript

I have this site that I am making. I want to update a global variable from another function. The global variable `i` is initialized to 0. I created 2 functions, 1 to update the global variable and display the new value by alert, and second a function that will just alert the new value of the updated global variable. The problem now is when I call the first function, it alerts the new updated value, but when I call the second function it alerts the original value which is zero.

Here's my code:-

```
 var i=0; var users=new Array(); 
 var password=new Array(); 
 users[0]="clydewinux";
 password[0]="moonfang";
 users[1]="freddipasquale";
 password[1]="evastar182";

 function verifyInput() {   //function one
    var u = login.username.value;
    var p = login.password.value;
    for (var c = 0; c <= 1; c++) {
        if (u === users[c] && p === password[c]) {
            i++;
            alert(i);
            window.location.replace("login.htm");
            break;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("username").value = "Invalid username...";
            window.location.href("home.htm");
            break;
        }
    }
}

function logout() {  //function two
    alert(i);
    window.location.replace("home.htm");
}
```

*Note; function verifyInput() is the first function, and function logout is the second.

Comment: I ran your code through http://jsbeautifier.org/. Readable code means more people will help you.

Comment: No. location.replace means go to the location and replace the entry in history for this page with the site to go

Comment: How do you declare i? Please append some code.

Comment: i declared i=0; what i want is when the user clicks the login button the value of i would be incremented. it works on the first function but not on the second function when i try to alert it..

Comment: FYI, `i` is a horrible name for a global variable.  It only takes one `for` loop that uses `i` as it's index who forgets to declare the `i` as a local variable and your global variable is trounced.  At least pick a global variable name that is likely to be unique and not accidentally used by something else.  Even better use the `module` design pattern to create one global object with your globals as properties of that object.

Comment: Are you trying to check client-side the password ? This is a terrible idea : it's easy to circumvent client-side "protections".

Comment: i see.. thanks for the tips. what i am trying to do here is to create a login form,if the user have the correct username and password i would be equals to 1..this value will be regularly checked onload of each the page to see if the user is still logged in, there's also a logout button that when clicked will change the value of i back to zero (means logged out).. i can't do php, i am still a newbie..php is still a hardcore for me.. :-(

Answer (score 2):

When you call the first function, you change the page content by loading a new page.

Javascript variables aren't kept from one page to another one.

So `i` is a new value after you called `window.location.replace` or `window.location.href=`.

If you want to keep some values from one page to another one, you may use `localStorage` :

```
var i = parseInt(localStorage['i'] || '0', 10); // loads the old saved value of i
function verifyInput() {
    var u = login.username.value;
    var p = login.password.value;
    for (var c = 0; c <= 1; c++) {
        if (u === users[c] && p === password[c]) {
            i++;
            localStorage['i'] = i; // stores the incremented i
            alert(i);
            window.location.replace("login.htm"); // this ends the script and reload the page
            break; // this is useless : the script has ended
        } else {
            document.getElementById("username").value = "Invalid username...";
            window.location.href("home.htm"); // this is buggy
            break;
        }
    }
}

function logout() {
    alert(i);
    window.location.replace("home.htm");
}
```

Side note : `window.location.href("home.htm");` wouldn't work : use `window.location.href = "home.htm";`

Comment: i am sorry i missed some codes. on top of all functions i declared these:
var i=0;
var users=new Array();
var password=new Array();
users[0]="clydewinux";
password[0]="moonfang";
users[1]="freddipasquale";
password[1]="evastar182";

Comment: this doesn't change the problem : calling `window.location.replace` erases all variables of the page.

Comment: That extra code is irrelevant :) dystroy is correct here, you need you need to store data somewhere between the pageloads, you may also use a cookie, which has better browser support.  Either way, what are you trying to achieve here? this doesn't look like it's going to be secure if it needs to be..

Comment: so should i use href instead? i tried it but it doesnt redirect to the new location. :-(

Comment: i am trying to make a login form, if the user have the correct username and password i would be equals to 1..this value will be regularly checked onload of each the page to see if the user is still logged in, there's also a logout button that when clicked will change the value of i back to zero (means logged out).. i can't do php, i am still a newbie..php is still a hardcore for me.. :-(

Comment: So it's just a learning exercise? What do you plan on the login allowing the user to do?

Comment: yes i am still a student, and very interested on web development. i wanna make a simple login form, if the user have typed the correct username and password it would redirect to a new page where the user can have admin privileges like edit the site. i can send you all my files if you want.