# Javascript updating global variable from function not working

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript global variable is not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016498/javascript-global-variable-is-not-updating)

I have this site that I am making. I want to update a global variable from another function. The global variable statCheck is initialized to 0. I created 2 functions, 1 to update the global variable and display the new value by alert, and second a function that will just alert the new value of the updated global variable. The problem now is when I call the first function, it alerts the new updated value, but when I call the second function it alerts the original value which is zero. Here's my code:

```
var statCheck=0;

var users=new Array();
var password=new Array();
users[0]="clydewinux";
password[0]="moonfang";
users[1]="freddipasquale";
password[1]="evastar182";

function verifyInput(){
var u=login.username.value;
var p=login.password.value;
for (var c=0;c<=1;c++){
    if(u===users[c]&&p===password[c])
        { 
        statCheck=1; 
        alert(statCheck);
        window.open("login.htm", '_self'); 
        break;}
    else
        {document.getElementById("username").value="Invalid username..."; 
        window.open("home.htm", '_self'); 
        break;}
    }

        }

function logout(){
alert(statCheck);
window.open("home.htm", '_self');
}
```

*Note; function verifyInput() is the first function, and function logout is the second.

Comment: Password verification: you're doing it *very* wrong. First of all, you're using JavaScript, which means it can be easily bypassed. Then, you're including the passwords in plaintext in your source code, for all to see. This is *literally* the worst possible thing you could do to verify passwords. It's worse than not checking at all.

Comment: you've already asked this question, why are you asking it again?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016498/javascript-global-variable-is-not-updating

Comment: i am sorry, i can't seem to fix it yet..yeah password verification using javascript not php..

Comment: Don't ask questions twice... update your existing question with necessary/requested information, comment on answers, etc and: be patient.

Comment: @NullUserException: While I agree with you, such a comment without any further information/explanation is not particularly helpful (I'm doing this too often as well, unfortunately...).

Comment: I'm very sorry.. T.T i can't wait to learn

Answer (score 1):

When using global variables, it is a good idea to make them explicitly global:

```
window.statCheck = 0;
// ...
window.statCheck = 1;
// ...
alert(window.statCheck);
```

This also helps with readability of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work..:-(